# How, in this insertion sort, does the array sort? I don't understand how the algorithm doesn't make the whole array the same number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

```
public static void insertionSort (int [] array)
{
    int shift, iterate, lock;

    for (iterate = 1; iterate < array.length; iterate++)
    {
        lock = array [iterate];
        shift = iterate - 1;

        // I don't understand this while loop. Wouldn't the whole array 
        // be 1 number afterwards?

        while (shift >= 0 && array [shift] > lock)
        {
            array [shift + 1] = array [shift];
            shift = shift - 1;
        }
        array [shift + 1] = lock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you think that the whole array would be 1 number afterwards? Then we can look at where the gap is in your reasoning.

Comment: Suggest you step through the code and watch it in action.

Comment: Just about every Java environment has a debugger that will allow you to single-step through the program on sample data and watch values change. Learning this tool and figuring it out yourself will be much better for you in the long run than having someone explain. An unrelated note: the choices of variable names here are  strange.